# PFQueryTableViewController has line going through cells when pushed

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController in my app.  If it is a root view of a controller, it is fine.  However, if I push it onto another view, there is a strange line that goes through the top of each cell.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Prayers";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 20;

    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    self.theObject = object;

    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.profileName.text = object[@"Title"];
    cell.contentLabel.text = object[@"Request"];
    cell.firstName = object[@"FirstName"];
    cell.lastName = object[@"LastName"];
    cell.iostoken = object[@"DeviceID"];
    cell.request = object[@"Title"];
    cell.prayerObject = object;
    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"ProfilePic"];
    cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon60x60@2x.png"];
    [cell.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapCommentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.commentButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

        UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];

        cell.profilePic.image = thumbnailImage;

    }];
    NSString *dates = object[@"dateMade"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM_dd_yyyy"];
   NSDate *datefromstring = [formatter dateFromString:dates];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [formatter2 stringFromDate:datefromstring];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:15];
    UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:12];



    return cell;
}
```

Just having this as root view presents this:

[image]

If I present it from another view like this:

```
-(void)myPrayers {
    BlogView1 *prayers = [[BlogView1 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:prayers animated:YES];

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: just a side note : your tab icons are pixilated probably because your not adding the @2x to file name of your pictures for supporting retina displays. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a `UITableViewCellSeperatorStyle` Property needing to be set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`...

```
    [_table setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

OR

set the separator color of your `UITableViewCell` to clear color

```
    [_table setSeparatorColor:<#(UIColor *)#>]
```

Comment: Does it fix the issue? Btw I like your cell :)